# Advanced ajaxform with 2 models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-ajax

I'm looking for any ideas/tutorials or maybe the name of that method. I'd like to create something like this on the screenshot.

We have 2 tables.

- `Order` (Order_Id, OrderName)
- `Item` (Item_Id, ItemName)

Functionality:

- user is able to add item to `Item` table by that form
- user after button has been clicked, the user is able to choose item from `Item` table and add it to the `Order` table
- everything should be related

[image: img_form]

P.S: What is that when sb is writing for example "Door" in textbox an under the textbox appears some data from DB which we are able to click and then the form is filled with that data?

Comment: "I'm looking for any ideas/tutorials" => Questions asking us to recommend or find a **book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow**. Please read [ask]

Comment: Thank you for help. I really appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

Add a column on  item table, name "OrderId" , set not null and add a foreign key to table orders to primary key.

Then read a tutorial for collections and entity framework